# how to do Database.QueryAysnc in xamarin

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I get a syntax error on this query:

```
public Task<List<ContactsModel>> JoinAttendeesAsync()
        {
            return Database.QueryAsync<ContactsModel>("SELECT * FROM [ContactsModel] JOIN [AttendeesModel] ON [AttendeesModel][ID]=[ContactsModel][ID]");
        }
```

What is the correct way to structure the sql statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following SQL to make a query. You do not need to use `[]` outside your table. Just use table and property directly in the SQL.

```
public Task<List<ContactsModel>> JoinAttendeesAsync()
{
    return Database.QueryAsync<Note>("SELECT * FROM ContactsModel JOIN AttendeesModel ON AttendeesModel.ID = ContactsModel.ID");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with Xamarin (or even QueryAsync) - it's just basic SQL syntax

```
SELECT * FROM ContactsModel
JOIN AttendeesModel ON AttendeesModel.ID = ContactsModel.ID
```